# Unable to deploy Spark jobs using Oozie

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, oozie

I need to keep a spark job running 24/7 and for this I am using Oozie. To do this I have written a workflow.xml and `job.properties` files, containing the needful information to invoke it.

However when I try to send the oozie job using this:

```
oozie job –config /home/oozie/tst/job.properties -run
```

I get the following error message, which is very clear:

```
java.io.IOException: configuration is not specified
        at org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.getConfiguration(OozieCLI.java:816)
        at org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.jobCommand(OozieCLI.java:1055)
        at org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.processCommand(OozieCLI.java:686)
        at org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.run(OozieCLI.java:639)
        at org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.main(OozieCLI.java:225)
configuration is not specified
```

The problem here is that the configuration file (`job.properties`) exists locally on the path specified. I also *PUT* the directory containing both files and .jar in the HDFS.

Any idea why is this failing?

Is Oozie the best tool for this task I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The config parameter takes local path not HDFS. check job.properties present in `/home/oozie/tst/job.properties`

check job.properties contain `oozie.wf.application.path=PATH_TO_HDFS_PATH_WHERE_WORKFLOW.XML_IS_PRESENT`

Plus I see the dash(-) given in config parameter is different then dash(-) in run parameter

Comment: 1- Yes, the file exists locally and the path is local too.

2- This exists in my `job.properties` file with the HDFS path.

Comment: In fact this was the problem. I am shocked.
Thank you a lot for the eagle eye.

Answer (score 2):

Specify the host in your command

```
oozie job --oozie http://your_host:11000/oozie -config /home/oozie/tst/job.properties -run
```

11000 is deafult port

Comment: I already tried, had the same output:
`[oozie@hdpgw01 tst]$ oozie job -oozie hdpgw01:11000/oozie –config /home/oozie/tst/job.properties -submit
java.io.IOException: configuration is not specified
        at org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.getConfiguration(OozieCLI.java:816)
        at org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.jobCommand(OozieCLI.java:981)
        at org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.processCommand(OozieCLI.java:686)
        at org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.run(OozieCLI.java:639)
        at org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.main(OozieCLI.java:225)
configuration is not specified
`